# Bounds on spectral radius of $2\text{diag}(h)+h \cdot 1^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-radius

How can I get lower/upper bounds on the largest eigenvalue of the following sum of diagonal and rank-1 matrices for vector $h$ with $h_i>0\ \forall i$:

$$A=2\text{diag}(h)+h \cdot 1^T$$
For instance, for $d=3$ it would be matrix below

$$2 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 h_1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & h_2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & h_3 \\
\end{array}
\right)+\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 h_1 & h_1 & h_1 \\
 h_2 & h_2 & h_2 \\
 h_3 & h_3 & h_3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The following has been observed to be an upper bound empirically
$$2\max_i h_i+\sum_i h_i\ge\lambda_\text{max}(A)$$

If we let $h=1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots,\frac{1}{d}$, then for $d=4000$, the answer is $\approx 9.29455$, proposed upper bound is 10.8714. Furthermore, relative difference between bound and true value seems bounded as we vary $h$

Motivation: $\alpha<\lambda_1(A)$ is necessary and sufficient for the iteration $w=w-\alpha \langle w, x\rangle x$ to converge when $x$ is sampled from centered Normal with diagonal covariance and $h_i$ on the diagonal ([derivation](http://yaroslavvb.com/convergence.pdf))

Comment: Your empirical upper bound can be confirmed using the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), or perhaps more simply using the [induced 1-norm or induced $\infty$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms) (since any matrix norm gives an upper bound to the spectral radius).

Comment: Is there a trick I can use for lower bound? Gershgorin disk for $h_1$ has radius $log(d)$ for $h=1,1/2,1/3,...$ so this bounds gets more loose with dimensions.... meanwhile empirically the gap shrinks as 1/sqrt(d)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Perhaps you should add information about $h_i$'s, e.g. $h_i>0, \forall i$. Also, in title, you used spectral radius, and in main body, you used  the largest eigenvalue.

Comment: @RiverLi added clarification that $h_i>0$. This means spectal radius=largest eigenvalue, by Perron-Frobenius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some thoughts**:

We deal with the case $h_1 > h_2 > \cdots > h_n$.

Consider the equation $Ax = \lambda x$ ($x\ne 0$) which is written as
$$(\lambda - 2h_k) x_k = h_k\sum_{i=1}^n x_i, \quad k=1, 2, \cdots, n. \tag{1}$$

We claim that $\lambda \ne 2h_j, \forall j$. Indeed,
if $\lambda = 2h_j$ for some $j$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 0$ and $(2h_j - 2h_k)x_k = 0, \forall k\ne j$ which results in $x_k = 0, \forall k \ne j$. Then we get $x = 0$. Contradiction.

From $\lambda \ne 2h_j, \forall j$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ne 0$.
From (1), we have
$$x_k = \frac{h_k}{\lambda - 2h_k}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i, \quad k=1, 2, \cdots, n. $$
Thus, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{h_k}{\lambda - 2h_k} = 1. \tag{2}$$

**Fact 1**: The equation (2) has exactly $n$ distinct real solutions $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2 > \cdots > \lambda_n$
with $\lambda_1 > 2h_1$ and $\lambda_k \in (2h_k, 2h_{k-1}), k=2, 3, \cdots, n$.
(The proof is easy and thus omitted here.)

Let us give a lower bound of $\lambda_1$.

We have
$$\frac{h_k}{\lambda_1 - 2h_k} = \frac{h_k}{\lambda_1}\cdot \frac{1}{1 - 2h_k/\lambda_1} > \frac{h_k}{\lambda_1} \cdot \left(1 + \frac{2h_k}{\lambda_1}\right), \quad \forall k.$$
Thus, we have
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n h_i}{\lambda_1} + \frac{2\sum_{i=1}^n h_i^2}{\lambda_1^2} < 1$$
which results in
$$\lambda_1 > \frac12 \sum_{i=1}^n h_i
+ \frac12\sqrt{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n h_i\right)^2 + 8 \sum_{i=1}^n h_i^2}. \tag{3}$$

When $h = 1, \frac12, \frac13, \cdots, \frac1d$ and $d = 4000$, (3) gives $\lambda_1 > 9.227851206$. Using Maple, from (2), we get $\lambda_1 \approx 9.294554415$.

**A better lower bound**:

We have
$$\frac{h_1}{\lambda_1 - 2h_1} + \frac{\sum_{i=2}^n h_i}{\lambda_1} + \frac{2\sum_{i=2}^n h_i^2}{\lambda_1^2} < 1. \tag{4}$$

When $h = 1, \frac12, \frac13, \cdots, \frac1d$ and $d = 4000$, (4) gives $\lambda_1 > 9.284803103$.

Comment: I'm wondering if better bounds exist if we know that $R=(\sum_i h_i)^2/(\sum_i h_i^2)$ is large. For general $h$, the bounds above can be off by factor of 80 in 200 dimensions. But I'm finding empirically for $R>100$, the two extreme distributions you provided in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4633085/bounds-on-max-i-p-i-in-terms-of-sum-i-p-i2 serve to bound the ratio $\lambda_1/(\|h\|_1+2\|h\|_\infty)$

Comment: Plotting the ratio for a variety of spectra against $R$ https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF0sa.png

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov The task is to give a good bound of $\lambda_1$ based on (2). We can do better such as (4) which does not admit closed form bounds.

Comment: OK, actually, plotting true value divided by your lower bound from (4) seems to converge to 1 as $R$ increases for all the families I tried -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADGYP.png ... is it obvious why this should happen?

Comment: Forked into separate question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4647281/largest-value-of-lambda-1-in-frach-1-lambda-1-2h-1-frac-sum-i-2

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov We need to compare the bound (4) with $\|h\|_1 + 2 \|h\|_\infty$?

Comment: yes. Empirically, value obtained by optimizing Bound (4) seems to converge to $\|h\|_1+2\|h\|_\infty$ as $R(h)=\frac{\sum_i (h_i)^2}{\sum_i h_i^2}$ goes to infinity, so it would be useful to know if its true

Answer (score 2):

We show the bound holds, and show lower bound of $\sum h_j$.

For simplicity, I assume all $h_i$ are real and $h_i>0$ (and $h_1\geq h_2...\geq h_d$).
Let's write out the eigenvalue-eigenvector equations, for an eigenvector
$(v_1, ... ,v_d)$  with $\sum v_j=1$ (this exists for $\lambda$ of maximal modulus by Perron-Frobenius).

$$2h_iv_i+h_i \sum v_j = \lambda v_i$$
$$2h_iv_i+h_i = \lambda v_i$$
$$ h_i=(\lambda-2h_i)v_i$$

If $\lambda-2h_i=0$ for some $i$ then $h_i=0$ for that $i$, but we agreed this does not happen. Hence $v_i=\frac{h_i}{\lambda-2h_i}$
and

$$\sum \frac{h_i}{\lambda-2h_i}=1$$

If $|\lambda| > 2h_1+\sum h_j$ (let's denote $2h_1+\sum h_i$ by $l$)  then

$$|\lambda -2h_i|> |\lambda|-2h_i>\sum h_j$$

$$|\sum \frac{h_i}{\lambda-2h_i}|\leq \sum | \frac{h_i}{\lambda-2h_i} | < |\sum \frac{h_i}{\sum h_j}|=1.$$

Contradiction, so, in fact, $|\lambda| \leq 2h_1+\sum h_i$.

Now, conversely, any root of the equation

$$\sum \frac{h_i}{\lambda-2h_i}=1$$

is an eigenvalue -- just take corresponding $v_i=\frac{h_i}{\lambda-2h_i}$ to get an eigenvector.

So we just need to show that for some $\epsilon>0$ we have for  the function $f(\epsilon)= \sum \frac{h_i}{l-\epsilon -2h_i} \geq 1$. Since at $\epsilon =0$ it is $\leq 1$, there will be some value between $l-\epsilon$ and $l$ (inclusive) where it is $1$. If we take $\epsilon =2 h_1$ we have

$$f(\epsilon)=\sum \frac{h_i}{\sum h_j - 2h_i}>\sum \frac{h_i}{\sum h_j}=1$$

So we get a lower bound which is $2 h_1$ away from the upper.

(Note that the bound you wanted originally, i.e. $\lambda_{max}> H_d+2-C d^{-0.5}$, then boils down to proving $\sum_1^d \frac{\frac{1}{j}}{H_d+2-\frac{2}{j} - C d^{-0.5}}>1$ for some $C$ (independent of $d$). Here $H_d=\sum_1^d \frac{1}{j}$.)

Update: I am a bit suspicious. Some computations seem to suggest the asymptotic value in the $h_j=1/j$ case is actually  $H_d$, i.e. the absolute gap (upper bound - spectral radius) limits to $2$ and relative one decays as $2/\ln d$.

Comment: (Already +1 some hours ago) A question: Let $n = 3$ and $h_1 = h_2 = 2, h_3 = 1$. Then $4$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, from $Av = 4v$ where $v = [v_1, v_2, v_3]^T$, we get $v_1 + v_2 + v_3 = 0$. But you let $\sum v_j=1$, so you don't consider the eigenvalue $4$ in my example?

Comment: You are right. One can either 1) restrict to the case of distinct $h_i$ as you do in your answer or 2) restrict to the case of the largest eigenvalue, where Perron-Frobenius guarantees an eigenvector with positive entries. I've added this to my answer. Thanks!