# Bounds on $\max_i p_i$ in terms of $\sum_i p_i^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, inequality

Suppose $(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_d)$ is a discrete probability distribution over $d$ outcomes with $p_i\ge p_{i+1}$

Given the value of $\rho=\sum_{i=1}^d p_i^2$ (aka [purity](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/linear-entropy)), what are the possible values of $p_1$?

I'm particularly interested in "large-d" regime.

Below is the graph of purity vs $p_1$ for distributions of the form $p_i\propto i^{-c}$. Does the set of feasible points $(\rho,p_1)$  concentrate around this curve when $d\to \infty$?

[image]

<sup><sub>[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-R-vs-r-plot.nb)</sub></sup>

Animating the bounds provided in answer below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried

Comment: $ \rho = \sum_{i=1}^d p_i^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^d p_1^2= p_1^2 d $ 

so we can see that $ |p_1| \geq \sqrt{\frac{\rho}{d}}$.

Comment: @DogeChan what about bound from the other direction? If we let $p_i\propto 1/i$, then $p_1\approx C \sqrt{\rho}$ for large $d$, wondering if that can be turned into upper bound

Comment: Since this is a probability distribution, $p_1 \leq 1 $ is guaranteed. Though I don't see how to get anything else out of this as there are quite a few possible examples of distributions with $p_1$ being extremely close to 1 with any other probabilities being almost zero.

Comment: Maybe Cauchy-Schwarz would be useful:
$$1 = \left(\sum_i p_i\right)^2 \le \left(\sum_i p_i^2\right) \left(\sum_i 1^2\right) = \rho d$$

Comment: @DogeChan $1/d$ may be as good as it gets as uniform bound, but I'm wondering if you can get a better bound on $p_1$ that's **non-uniform**, ie in terms of $\rho$, added a graph to post to show what I mean

Comment: Since $\max_{1 \leq i \leq d} |p_i|, \sum_{i = 1}^d |p_i|,$ and $\left( \sum_{i = 1}^d |p_i|^2 \right)^{1/2}$ are all norms on $\mathbb{R}^d$, they are *equivalent*, meaning there will exist $d$-dependent constants $A_d, B_d \in (0, \infty)$ such that $A_d \left( \sum_{i = 1}^d |p_i|^2 \right)^{1/2} \leq \max_{1 \leq i \leq d} |p_i| \leq B_d \left( \sum_{i = 1}^d |p_i|^2 \right)^{1/2}$, and they can be computed. I suspect they'll be somewhat "trivial" or "obvious," in the sense that they're the bounds you could find quickly just by playing with the inequalities a bit.

Comment: @AJY nice observation, that explains the square-root shape of curve. I imagine formulas for low-dimensional case will be ugly, so the interesting case is when $d\to \infty$

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I don't know that they'd be especially ugly. The naive bounds would be
$\max_{1 \leq i \leq d} |p_i| \leq \left( \sum_{i = 1}^d |p_i|^\alpha \right)^{1/\alpha} \leq d^{1 / \alpha} \max_{1 \leq i \leq d} |p_i|$ for $1 \leq \alpha < \infty$, and those bounds are as good as they get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of $p_1$ is given by $[\alpha, \beta]$ where
$$\beta = \frac{1}{d} + \sqrt{\rho - \frac{\rho}{d} - \frac{1}{d} + \frac{1}{d^2}}$$
and
$$\alpha = \frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{m}\sqrt{\frac{m\rho - 1}{m-1}}$$
where $m = \lfloor 1/\rho\rfloor + 1$.
Moreover, $p_1 = \beta$ if $p_2 = p_3 = \cdots = p_d = \frac{1}{d} - \frac{1}{d}\sqrt{\frac{d\rho - 1}{d-1}}$;
$p_1 = \alpha$ if
$p_1 = p_2 = \cdots = p_{m-1} = \alpha$
and $p_m = \frac{1}{m} - \sqrt{\rho - \frac{\rho}{m} - \frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{m^2}}$ and $p_{m+1} = \cdots = p_d = 0$.

*Proof*:

(1) Prove that $p_1 \le \beta$

We have
$$1 - p_1 = p_2 + p_3 + \cdots + p_d
\le \sqrt{(d-1)(p_2^2 + p_3^2 + \cdots + p_d^2)} = \sqrt{(d-1)(\rho - p_1^2)}$$
or
$$-dp_1^2 + 2p_1 + d\rho - \rho - 1 \ge 0$$
which results in
$$p_1 \le \beta.$$

(2) Prove that $p_1 \ge \alpha$

Let $y_1 = y_2 = \cdots = y_{m-1} = \alpha$ and $y_m = \frac{1}{m} - \sqrt{\rho - \frac{\rho}{m} - \frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{m^2}}$ and $y_{m+1} = \cdots = y_d = 0$.

If $p_1 < \alpha$, then
$(p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_d)$ is majorized by
$(y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_d)$.
By [Karamata's inequality](https://www.detailedpedia.com/wiki-Karamata%27s_inequality),
we have
$$p_1^2 + p_2^2 + \cdots + p_d^2
< y_1^2 + y_2^2 + \cdots + y_d^2 = \rho.$$
This is impossible.

We are done.

Comment: Thanks! I especially like that you gave the examples of distributions which achieve $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov You are welcome.

Comment: btw these are pretty useful distributions, for instance they appear to be extreme cases of waiting times for "non-uniform" [birthday problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263368/birthday-problem-with-unequal-probability-expected-number-of-draws-before-the?noredirect=1&lq=1) over distributions with fixed $R=\|p\|^2$ ([notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-mean-time-to-collision.nb))

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Yes, it is interesting. By the way, the author of that question is Clement C who gave an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

You have:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^d p_i^2 \leq \max_i p_i \cdot \sum_{i=1}^d p_i = \max_i p_i
$$
while, by [monotonicity of $\ell_p$ norms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424281/monotonicity-of-ell-p-norm), $\|p\|_\infty = \max_i p_i \leq \|p\|_2$. So overall
$$
 \|p\|_\infty \leq \|p\|_2 \leq \sqrt{\|p\|_\infty} \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
which cannot be improved in general: the lower bound is tight for point masses ($p_1=1, p_i=0$ for $i\geq 2$), the upper bound is tight for the uniform distribution ($p_i = 1/d$ for all $i$).

With that in hand: back to your question, you can check that, given $\rho$, there exists some $\alpha = \rho^2 + O(1/d)$ such that, setting $p_1=\alpha^2$ and $p_i = \frac{1-\alpha}{d-1}$ for $i\geq 2$, we get $\|p\|_2^2=\rho$ and $\|p\|_\infty^2 = \alpha$.

On the other side, for $d$ large enough, setting $p_1=\dots=p_D=\rho^2$ for $D=\lfloor 1/\rho^2\rfloor$ and $p_i=\frac{1-D\rho^2}{d-D}$ for $i\geq D+1$, you get $\|p\|_2^2=\rho+o(1/d)$ and $\|p\|^2_\infty=\rho^4$.

So again, even under the impurity ("collision probability") constraint $\|p\|_2^2=\rho$, the inequality $(\dagger)$ cannot be improved.

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer!

Comment: By the way, why do you call this "collision probability"?

Comment: Oh. The squared $\ell_2$ is often called this way as it is exactly the probability that two independent draws from $p$ "collide" (take the same value).

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as an optimization problem, and in particular try using Langrange multipliers. Maximize $p_1$ subject to $\sum p_i = 1$ and $\sum p_i^2 = \rho$.

You should get the Langrangian:

$$
\mathcal{L}(p, \lambda, \mu) = p_1 + \lambda\bigl(\sum p_i - 1\bigr) + \mu \bigl(\sum p_i^2 - \rho\bigr).
$$

From there, you get the system of equations

$$
\begin{align}
p_1 + \lambda + 2\mu p_1 &= 0\\
\lambda + 2\mu p_i &= 0, \text{ for } i\ge2\\
\sum p_i &= 1\\
\sum p_i^2 &= \rho.
\end{align}
$$

Note that the constraint $p_i \ge p_{i+1}$ doesn't matter, because we can just rearrange them.

Solving the system will give you an expression for $p_1$ in terms of $\rho$.